# How to provide google services support on latest Huawei devices

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

We have recently launched our Android application on Google play store and Huawei app gallery, but on the latest Huawei phones, my application is not visible on both stores. We have used some google services such as google maps, google places APIs, etc.

Answer (score 2):

1. The new Huawei phones(Mate 30, Mate 40, P40...) does not have Google Play Store. If you cannot find your app in Google Play Store on your phone of other brands or an earlier Huawei phones, plz contact Paly Store support.
2. Your app has integrated GMS. As new Huawei phones are banned from using GMS, you app, if with GMS integrated, will be unable to run on new Huawei phones. If you want your app to run on these phones, integrate [Huawei Mobile Services (HMS)](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/hms).

If you want to use the map service in your app, and also want your app to run on both Huawei phones and Google Android phones, you can integrate both GMS Map Kit and HMS Map Kit. Then your app will use HMS Map Kit on Huawei phones, while using GMS Map Kit on Google Android phones.

[Map Kit docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-sdk-brief-introduction-0000001061991343)

[Map Kit demo on Github](https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-mapkit-demo)

---

You can use G+H solution: the HMS+GMS adaptation layer code is added to the original logic code. Add the following code to determine whether GMS APIs or HMS APIs are available and call the available APIs:

```
public boolean  isGMS(){
    return GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
}
public boolean  isHMS(){
    return HuaweiApiAvailability.getInstance().isHuaweiMobileServicesAvailable(this) == com.huawei.hms.api.ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
}
The logic of the code invoking:
If ( isGMS() ) {
//GMS code
}else if ( isHMS() ){
//HMS code
}
```

You can also use [HMS ToolKit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/overview-0000001050060881) to implement G2H/G+H.